# Linux ELF - Why does normal linking run faster than 'ldd -r'?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, ld, elf

I have an exe in which none of the code changed, but I am afraid that it links to symbols that no longer exist on its shared objects. I found two ways to test that:

- Run `ldd -r`
- Relink the exe

In some cases it seems like relinking is faster than running `ldd -r` what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

> In some cases it seems like relinking is faster than running ldd -r what is the reason for this?

Consider a simple case: `main.o` calls `foo()` from `libfoo.so`, and is linked like this:

```
gcc main.o -L. -lfoo
```

The amount of work `ld` has to do: discover that `foo` is being called, find that it is defined in `libfoo.so`, done. Not very much work.

Now suppose that `libfoo.so` itself has been linked against `libbar.so`, and calls 10000000 different symbols from it.

What does `ldd -r` have to do? It will first look in `a.out` for any unresolved symbols (there is only one: `foo`), and find a definition for it in `libfoo.so` (easy). Next it has to consider every undefined symbol in `libfoo.so`, and find a definition for all of them as well (in `libbar.so`). That is about 1000000 times harder. Repeat for `libbar.so`, and every other library linked into it.

It should not then be very surprising then that under above conditions `ld` will take significantly less time than `ldd -r`.

Comment: But `ld` also checks the calls from `libfoo` to `libbar`, doesn't it?